# Using Eclipse Kepler and installed EGit plugin, but not getting git option in Team

Tags: force.com, eclipse, git, github

[image: Eclipse Version]

[image: installed Egit]

I am not getting git option in Open Perspective window. Not sure why. I am trying to get the git repository connected. I am new to git and want to learn how to do this. I have gone through the article written by Jitender Zaa, but he used Eclipse Indigo, I have kepler.

Please help.

[image: No Git option available]

Comment: Are you restricted to using eclipse? there are other IDE's for developing with Salesforce.

Comment: Hi glls, I am actually trying to do it with Force.com IDE Eclipse, as we are using it in our current project. But thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Get the egit eclipse latest updates from **Help->Install New Software**
http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates

and check again.

Comment: I did that, but no help yet. Any other suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please restart your Eclipse from the command line with option **-clean** (e,g. eclipse.exe -clean)  and check again, please?